# Losing data when battery runs out

Tags: android

We have a strange bug. Our App will loose it's data (stored in SQLite) if the battery runs out but it doesn't if we kill the application forcefully and then the battery runs out.

We're not sure what could cause this.

EDIT 1:

WHAT DOES IT MEAN TO LOOSE THE DATA?

1. When the user registers we save his username etc.
2. When the app is closed, forced-closed and the user opens the app again the username is there
3. When the battery runs out and the app is running in foreground. After the battery is recharged and  the user opens the app again, the username is gone.

How are objects stored:

```
 public Void perform(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                final ConfigEntry entry = new ConfigEntry(property, value);

                if(contains(property)) {
                    db.update(ConfigEntry.TABLE_NAME, databaseAdapter.convertToContentValues(entry), ConfigEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " = ?", new String[] { property });
                } else {
                    db.insertOrThrow(ConfigEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, databaseAdapter.convertToContentValues(entry));
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

So basically db.insertOrThrow is called.

This is how we initialize the database:

```
public  S doInTransaction(TransactionTask task) {
        DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDb.setLockingEnabled(true);
        mDb.beginTransaction();
        try {
            S result = task.perform(mDb);
            mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return result;
        } finally {
            mDb.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please consider explaining *precisely* what you mean by "loose it's data".

Comment: Even we are not sure what do you mean by "App will loose it's data"?

Comment: Is this  while inserting data in transcation? You need to commit the transation if it is.

Comment: @wtsang02 if he missed committing data, it should be problem always, not only at the time of battery runs out, No!! :)

Comment: @Ankit Just wondering if he does commiting data onPause()/onStop or similar

Comment: Basically the database is not saved if the battery runs out. Killing the app from settings is OK. It's only if the battery runs out.

Comment: @wtsang02 yeah have possibility.

Comment: @daniel are you doing nythin on PHONE_BOOT up? May we see how you are actually saving data. and delete method too if any!!

Comment: Added code to save our date. And no, we don't do anything on PHONE_BOOT

Comment: @daniel and how/when is this executed? Clicking a button? or activity exits?

Comment: @wtsang02 clicking a button. We know this is executing as data is saved and execution continues. We know that if battery runs out the data gets erased.

Comment: @daniel did you read my first comment? Are you using transcation mode? If so, that is the problem.

Comment: @wtsang02 What do you mean by transaction mode? I couldn't find anything in the android docs.

Comment: @daniel Did you call beginTransaction() after you call database.open() , [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: @wstang02 yes we do:       SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        mDb.setLockingEnabled(true);
        mDb.beginTransaction();

Comment: *loose* - adj.: the opposite of tight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all the Help, we finally found the answer.

We are encrypting our database using a user password and salting the password with the **MAC adddress** of the device.

What happened is that sometimes when the user ran out of battery after the boot, when our app was ran and we requested for the MAC address it failed because the network card it's still disabled or something. In that case we created a new salt which when trying to read the DB would fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `beginTransaction()`. If you have call  `beginTransaction()` you need to call:

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

below or your data **Will NOT be saved**. The reason is here in the [sqlite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)
 

 And the reason why your data isn't saving is, if you started transaction and  `db.setTransactionSuccessful();`wasn't called because of the system tried to close it,then data will not be saved. However `finally{}` might still be called but that doesn't change the fact that `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` wasn't called.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be saved if we setTransactionSuccessful and db.endTransaction. I don't get how else can we do it.

Comment: I think you mean If you don't have this call your data Will not be saved? Right now it reads as if you have the code your data will not be save. I don't know who downvoted.

Comment: There are many more factors than simply *how much* data you're working with when considering whether or not to use transactions

Comment: We have that already from the beginning. Look at my initial post, I posted our transactional model.

Comment: @Madbreaks That is why I added in () the results. I think he will understand if each call will be saved, that means its hard to rollback

Comment: I don't get the answer here because it is basically already said in the question... he is doing exactly as you said

Comment: @WarrenFaith He added that after I post the answer stating the problem

Comment: Anyway this is not the problem.

Comment: which just makes your answer totally obsolete - so I wonder who votes up and down and up and down...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I hope I can provide some questions or inspiration to dig deeper:

1. Have you monitored if your database goes through the complete initial creation process or are the tables there but only the username missing? Can you download the database file from the device and check the content in an SQLite tool on your PC?
2. You open the database inside `doInTransaction()` but you don't close it there:

   ```
   public S doInTransaction(TransactionTask task) {
       DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(mContext);
       SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       //mDb.setLockingEnabled(true); // true is default, so it can be removed
       mDb.beginTransaction();
       S result = null;
       try {
           result = task.perform(mDb);
           mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
       } finally {
           // rolls back if setTransactionSuccessful() wasn't called
           mDb.endTransaction();
           mDb.close();
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. Are you completely sure that you use the same database? I ask because I saw it once that someone used a timestamp as part of the database name.
4. You are not creating an [in-memory database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#create%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%29) by mistake?
5. There are multiple different ways for a device to die of low battery: It might just drop dead or it manages to actually make an emergency shut down. Which one is the case? Have you any logging that might provide some inside of what your app does when it goes off?

To sum up: I doubt that the reason is in the code you provided and as you mentioned, the code is only executed when a button is pressed. That leaves the above questions for further investigation (there are, of course, some I might have missed...).